# How to detect double click on element by registering only click event

Tags: javascript

I can't use event `dblClick` I can add event listener only to `click` event.
Is it possible to detect double click on element () with registering only click event?
I add event like:

```
for (var i....)... {
...addEventListener('click', function(event)
```

Comment: Remember if you've seen two clicks in rapid succession?

Comment: I´m not sure why you can´t use dblclick..It feels like a kind of dirty solution for me but you could just track if the click event has been triggered twice in a specific amount of time. e.g.: 200-500 ms

Comment: _"I can't use event `dblClick`"_ Why? That's literally what you're supposed to use.

Comment: I am adding script to react native webview. And it recognize only click not dblClick

Comment: @1110: I find that **very** hard to believe. Citation?

Comment: If I put addEventListener('click', function(event) it works but addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) doesn't do anything.
Don't know if it's important I am trying to add dbclick to image tags.

Comment: @1110 if you manipulate element within the click handler, it's possible browser loose the context of dblclick and doesn't trigger it anymore (facing similar situation in our app). I'd be almost certain that there is a code in your app that disrupt it as well. Using manual solution is "fine" but probably just cover the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and you can adjust your timeout to suit your needs.

```js
function makeDoubleClick(doubleClickCallback, singleClickCallback) {
    var clicks = 0, timeout;
    return function() {
        clicks++;
        if (clicks == 1) {
            singleClickCallback && singleClickCallback.apply(this, arguments);
            console.log('single click');
            timeout = setTimeout(function() { clicks = 0; }, 400);
        } else {
            timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
            console.log('double click');
            doubleClickCallback && doubleClickCallback.apply(this, arguments);
            clicks = 0;
        }
    };
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', makeDoubleClick(), false);
```

```html
<button id='btn'>
  Click Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of impossibility to use double click event listener, you can try to use last click flag and timeout to check if next click happens in short period of time. If it happens then it is signal of double click. Something like this:

```
var dblClickCheck = false;
var timeout;

element.addEventListener('click', function () {

    if(timeout){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    if(dblClickCheck){
        alert('double click');
        return;
    }

    dblClickCheck = true;

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        dblClickCheck = false;
    }, 200);

}, false);
```

You need to set delay of `setTimeout` depending on your own situation

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds an event listener to the button that goes away after 300 milliseconds. So when the button isn't pressed twice within 300 ms, the inner function doesn't fire.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("dbl_click");

var outerFunction = function(event) {
  button.addEventListener('click', innerFunction);
  setTimeout(function(){ button.removeEventListener('click', innerFunction) }, 300);
};

var innerFunction = function(event) {
  alert("double clicked!");
}

button.addEventListener('click', outerFunction);
```

```html
<div>
<button id="dbl_click">Double click me!</button>
</div>
```